# Gradle is not downloading Jax RS libraries

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to download and add JaxRS libraries with gradle. Here is the build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

jar {
    baseName = 'rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

dependencies {
    compile('javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:1.1.1')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not downloading them? I've just applied your exact script and the dependencies are located fine

Comment: I dont know about you, but because I'm living in Iran, some sites filtered my IP, and I have the exact same problem with jax (I was using maven not gradle) so I use a proxy and changed my IP and then it worked like charm :D if you are in place like Iran that sanctions of US ban you from some IP try using a proxy(although it says in your profile that you live in US)

Comment: @MrWiggles It's not working for me when I try to `import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;` It does not work.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav, the script is perfectly valid and gradle downloads the dependency without any problems in Poland. What you can do is to download the dependency manually, place it in *libs* folder and alter gradle script to include *libs* folder as dependencies. Will that work? Can you download this dependency manually?

Answer (score 0):

try with --debug and see the URL it is using to retrieve the dependency.  Then use curl or similar tool and see if it is available.  If you can't get to it through your browser or curl then networking issue.

Check maven central too, maybe they don't have that version anymore.  Just to validate.